Web3.py and cloud provider hardware security modules (HSM)
How can I use hardware security modules from different cloud service vendors like Google Cloud in Web3.py for signing Ethereum transactions?
E.g. use Cloud HSM to sign Web3.py Ethereum transactions.

Here is something I have been working on lately. https://github.com/Ankvik-Tech-Labs/web3-google-hsm.
It's a Python module which uses Google Cloud HSM to sign Web3 Ethereum transactions. You can use it as a module as well as a CLI tool

Install using pip

pip install web3-google-hsm

As A CLI Tool
# Specify explicitly
web3-google-hsm generate \
  --project-id my-project \
  --location us-east1 \
  --keyring eth-keyring \
  --key-id eth-key-1 \
  --retention-days 365

As a Module
Setup your env variables
# Add to ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile
export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT="your-project-id"
export GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION="us-east1"
export KEY_RING="eth-keyring"
export KEY_NAME="eth-key"
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/your/service-account.json"

# Apply changes
source ~/.bashrc  # or source ~/.bash_profile

Message Signing

from web3_google_hsm.accounts.gcp_kms_account import GCPKmsAccount

account = GCPKmsAccount()

# Get the Ethereum address derived from your GCP KMS key
print(f"GCP KMS Account address: {account.address}")

# Sign a message
message = "Hello Ethereum!"
signed_message = account.sign_message(message)

# Access signature components
print(f"R: {signed_message.r.hex()}")
print(f"S: {signed_message.s.hex()}")
print(f"V: {signed_message.v}")
print(f"Full signature: {signed_message.to_hex()}")

Detailed documentation: https://ankvik-tech-labs.github.io/web3-google-hsm/
